# Dynamically loading Images using file path in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to load  images dynamically using a local file path. All the images are stored inside the assets folder and a server api responds with which image to display on different screens. It is required to load images dynamically instead of hardcoding as I’m trying to render images randomly. Appreciate your support to resolve this.

This is the error I got when running the app while passing a filename as a parameter to `require()`. I'm aware that this works if it's hardcoded file path.

error: index.js: Invalid call at line 36: require(item)

```js
    import React,{useState} from "react";
    import { Text, View, Image, FlatList} from "react-native";
     
    const MyComponent=()=>{ 
    // this list is loaded from an api
    const imagesList = ["../../../assets/images/apple.png", "../../../assets/images/flower.png" ];
     return(
     <View>
        <FlatList
         contentContainerStyle={styles.grid} 
         numColumns={3}
         data={imagesList}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) =>index.toString()}
         renderItem={(item)=>{  
        //line 36 
         return(<Image source={require(item)} />); }} />
     </View>); 
    }
```

What I’m expecting to render is something like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0xqE.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
    import { Text, View, Image, FlatList} from "react-native";
     
    const MyComponent=()=>{ 
    // this list is loaded from an api
    const imagesList = [require("../../../assets/images/apple.png"), require("../../../assets/images/flower.png")];
     return(
     <View>
        <FlatList
         contentContainerStyle={styles.grid} 
         numColumns={3}
         data={imagesList}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) =>index.toString()}
         renderItem={(item)=>{  
        //line 36 
         return(<Image source={item} />); }} />
     </View>); 
    }
```

**Read official Doc**
https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

[image: Read official Doc]

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Question is to load the image dynamically meaning the path passed to require will be passed as a variable